# Capture profile of fragment of JavaScript program

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a piece of code which is crazy time consuming (reducer that does hardcore objects cloning etc...).

Is there a way to start/stop via JavaScript profiling in Chrome, or make some marks, so that I can easily spot where is the code I am interested in inside long profiler's data?

E.g.

```
// start profiling here e.g. Profiler.startProfiler()
callHardcoreFunction();
// end profiling here e.g. Profiler.startProfiler()
```

Comment: AFAIK the profiler can't do that (the closest thing is [profile/profileEnd](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#profilename_and_profileendname)), but you can inspect that single function in the `Bottom-Up` or `Call Tree` sub-panels.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to ... **make some marks**, so that I can easily spot where is the code I am interested in inside long profiler's data?

How about the [User Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/User_Timing_API)?

Add a mark to your code to signify the beginning of the chunk of work that you're interested in:

```
window.performance.mark('start');
```

And a mark to signify the end:

```
window.performance.mark('end');
```

And then calculate the duration:

```
window.performance.measure('duration', 'start', 'end');
```

And you can view this duration in the **User Timing** section of your Performance recording:

[image: User Timing]

In the screenshot example, I called the duration `form_interaction`.